# Random sampling in quantitative studys

Tags: sampling, survey-sampling

Many empirical studies are based on random samples which are used to draw conclusions about a corresponding population. In this context, the importance of a random sample is often pointed out.

As to my understanding, in a random sample, each element of the population has the same chance of being included in the sample.
Suppose I am conducting an experiment in which I want to study the effect of a commercial on a person's buying behavior (hypothetical example). Let's further assume that the study design includes a control group and a treatment group. The treatment group gets to see the commercial before making a purchase and the control group does not. I was asking myself where a sampling bias may occur and how it would affect the studys outcome. Whether I am able to relate results to the population should depend on the composition of my sample I guess? If my sample consists of 80% students, my results would not valid for the "average inhabitant of my city" but rather I have to relate the results to the population of students right? So if I want to relate a statement to a certain population, I have to make sure that the overall sample is representative for the population with respect to factors that may influence the variable of interest.

If I have now drawn a sample that represents my population accordingly, then in a next step I have to assign the participants of the sample to the treatment or control group. This assignment must also be done randomly to avoid bias in the results. I have now read in some articles that a test of balance is performed to make sure that the randomization of the groups worked. Ofte a two-sample t-test is used to see if the means of observable characteristics like age, gender, etc. in the two groups (control group and treatment group) are significantly different. However, in other articles I have also read that these tests are superfluous if one could ensure that the assignment to the two groups happened randomly. What are your opinions on this?